# Is there a way to replace the standard colour of a pie chart to a picture?

Tags: r, image, plot, ring

Is there a way to insert a picture as the 'colour' of a variable in a ring plot in R? I.e. the fill of the plot is a picture trimmed to what would traditionally be filled with a block colour? Can I do this with an image command where you'd normally specify colour in a plot?